# Bug in Cmd-Tabbing through windows on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I am on Mac OS X and I have this annoying problem when Cmd-tabbing through windows. When I want to switch windows, sometimes the new window appears for just a glimpse and then the old window appears. Same happens with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>.

When I have one Firefox window maximized and one not, then <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> does not work.

Any ideas how to make the <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> persistent and working?

Comment: Are you sure you mean `Alt-Tab`? This does nothing on OS X. You switch between windows of one application with `Cmd-\``, and whole applications with `Cmd-Tab`. Also note that you have to escape the backtick with a backslash `\\`` so it doesn't interpret it as code.

Comment: sorry I meant CMD

Comment: Do you have any third party window management software installed (Witch, etc.)? Does this happen on another user account as well?

Comment: no i dont have any third party